# mod_pagespeedを利用した時のPageSpeed画面での確認について

Tags: apache

mod_pagespeedを有効にした状態（設定はデフォルトのまま）で、https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/
で確認すると、画像の最適化が必要、という形で以下のようなファイル名のものが
x10311228024_6742e515d2_k.jpg.pagespeed.ic.5t2_fLEght.jpg
怒られてしまうのですが、このような場合どういう対処をすれば良いでしょうか？

よろしくお願い致します。